# Java String Parsing Without Regular Expressions

Tags: java, string, parsing

From a server, I get strings of the following form:

```
String x = "fixedWord1:var1 data[[fixedWord2:var2 fixedWord3:var3 data[[fixedWord4]    [fixedWord5=var5 fixedWord6=var6 fixedWord7=var7]]] , [fixedWord2:var2 fixedWord3:var3 data[[fixedWord4][fixedWord5=var5 fixedWord6=var6 fixedWord7=var7]]]] fixedWord8:fixedWord8";
```

(only spaces divide groups of word-var pairs)
Later, I want to store them in a `Hashmap`, like `myHashMap.put(fixedWord1, var1);` and so on.

**Problem:**
Inside the first *`"data[......]"`*-tag, the number of other *`"data[..........]"`*-tags is variable, and I don't know the length of the string in advance.

I don't know how to process such Strings without resorting to `String.split()`, which is discouraged by our assignment task givers (university).

I have searched the internet and couldn't find appropriate websites explaining such things.
It would be of great help, if experienced people could give me some links to websites or something like a *"diagrammatic plan"* so that I could code something.

**EDIT:**
got mistake in String (*off-topic-begin* "please don't lynch" *off-topic-end*), the right string is (changed fixedWord7=var7 ---to---> fixedWord7=[var7]):

```
String x = "fixedWord1:var1 data[[fixedWord2:var2 fixedWord3:var3 data[[fixedWord4]    [fixedWord5=var5 fixedWord6=var6 fixedWord7=[var7]]]] , [fixedWord2:var2 fixedWord3:var3 data[[fixedWord4][fixedWord5=var5 fixedWord6=var6 fixedWord7=[var7]]]]] fixedWord8:fixedWord8";
```

Comment: You could do a recursive algorithm looks like if you so desired.

Comment: You have to do this in java or can you use sed/awk and why can't you use regular expressions?

Comment: Maybe your university will allow usage of `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes or even `Scanner`? :) It's based on regex, however.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: i know what recursion is but cant think of any.<br/><br/>@Zaitsev i am going to search something and hope that it does the trick.

Comment: can you use StringTokenizer

Comment: although it is deprecated i would do so if it is better than my own attempt.

Comment: Are you sure you got the format of the string correct?  There seems to be duplicate data and no pattern to the content.

Comment: no im afraid, this is the string and inside the first "data"-tag there can be 0 to n other "data[]"-elements

Comment: I can't believe you've got an accepted answer. And of course, the question is ambiguous too. You should describe what the expected result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your string follows a same pattern, which has "data" and "[", "]" in it. And the variable name/value will not include these strings

1. remove string "data[", "[", "]", and "," from the original string

   ```
   replaceAll("data[", "")
   replaceAll("[", "")
   etc
   ```
2. separate the string by space: " " by using StringTokenizer or loop through the String char by char.
3. then you will get array of strings like

   ```
   fixedWorld1:var1
   fixedWorld2:var2
   ......
   fixedWorld4
   fixedWorld5=var5
   ......
   ```
4. then again separate the sub strings by ":" or "=". and put the name/value into the Map

Comment: which classe should i use for this

Comment: @kiltek I am not sure what are you asking?

Comment: the replaceAll method where is it and which combination of Pattern or whatever must i use.

Comment: you can use replaceAll directly to your string: x.replaceAll("data[", "")

Comment: this sounds also quite handy. could i also count how often data was replaced?  because then i would not overwrite values in my hashmap.

Comment: If you want to count how many times a string was replaced, you can use replaceFirst() method in a loop. The loop condition can be checking if the new returned string equals() to the old string. BTW, in your title, you said you can't use regular expression. So you should use replace() instead of replaceAll().

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not absolutely clear but may be something like this will work for you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)[:=]\\[?(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher( x );
while( m.find() ) {
   System.out.println( "matched: " + m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2) );
   hashMap.put ( m.group(1), m.group(2) );
}
```

Comment: this works superbly, but please i apologize, i have forgotten some sqaure brackets around fixedWord7=[var7], and thus above code omits that this string completely. I am going to edit my post.